# Finding the probably density function of $Z=\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$ where Y~N(0,1) and X~N(0,1)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

X and Y are normal random variables that are independant. Finding the probably density function of  $Z=\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$ where Y~N(0,1) and X~N(0,1).

Attempt:

Let $z \in R$. If $z \lt 0$ then $P(Z\le z)=0$ since $Z=\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}\ge 0$

Let $z\ge0$, then:

$$F_z(z)= P(Z\le z) = P(\sqrt{X^2+Y^2} \le z)= P(\sqrt{X^2+Y^2} \le z)     $$
This is where I'm stuck. I need to use $\phi=\frac12\left[1+erf\frac{x}{\sqrt2}\right] $ but I'm not sure how to continue with the inequality $P(\sqrt{X^2+Y^2} \le z) $ in order to be able to plug it into $\phi$.

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independent?

Comment: @Clarinetist yes I forgot to add. Thanks

Comment: Hint: $P(\sqrt{X^2+Y^2} \leq z)$ for $z>0$ is the integral of the joint density over a circle of radius $z$ centered at the origin. So change to polar coordinates. The integral is quite tractable (almost "magically" you get the factor you need to compute it...)

Comment: @Ian thank you for the hint, I got it solved. Would I be able to use the same strategy for $W=X^2+Y^2$?

Comment: Sure, though that correspondence has nothing to do with normality ($P(A^2 \leq a^2)=P(A \leq a)$, for positive r.v.s $A$).

Comment: @Ian what would my limits of integration be since this time its not really a circle? or can I define a "help" random variable, let's say $C^2=W=X^2+Y^2$ and then treat the limits as I would an integral over a circle?

Comment: It is a circle: $\{ x^2+y^2 \leq z \}$ is the disk of radius $\sqrt{z}$.

Comment: Damn, I always keep overthinking in this course. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way to do this is to note  for $c \geq 0$, $P(\sqrt{X^2+Y^2} \leq c) = P( X^2+Y^2 \leq c^2) = \iint_{\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \leq c} \frac{1}{2 \pi} e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2} dx dy = \iint_{0 \leq r \leq c, -\pi \leq \theta \leq \pi} \frac{r}{2 \pi} e^{-r^2/2} dr d\theta$ by a transformation to polar coordinates. This integral is easy to evaluate via substitution of $u=r^2$.

The result will be a rayleigh distribution.

Comment: thanks! What are the values for $\sigma$ and $\mu$ for Z~N($\sigma$, $\mu$)?

Answer (score 0):

Let $X, Y \overset{ind}{\sim}\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$. Then it is well-known that $X^2 + Y^2 = Z^2 \sim \chi^2_2$. Thus, $Z \sim \left(\chi^2_2\right)^{1/2}$. This is a monotonic transformation of the $\chi^2_2$ random variable.

Let $W \sim \chi^2_2$, so that $Z \sim W^{1/2}$. Then, as you can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution#Probability_density_function),
$$f_{W}(w) = \dfrac{x^{2/2-1}e^{-x/2}}{2^{2/2}\Gamma\left(\dfrac{2}{2} \right)} = \dfrac{1}{2}e^{-x/2}\text{.}$$
(This is particularly interesting... a $\chi^2_2$ distribution is just an exponential distribution.) Now if $Z \sim W^{1/2}$, $Z^2 \sim W$; hence,
$$f_{Z}(z) = f_{W}(z^2)\left|\dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}z}[z^2] \right| = \dfrac{2}{2}ze^{-z^2/2} = ze^{-z^2/2}\text{, } z > 0\text{.}$$